# How can I solve an error when booting from a USB?

Tags: installation, usb

I've been trying to install Ubuntu for last 2 days, and have gone through many webpages for help with no avail.

Here's what I did:
I downloaded `Unetbootin` and used it to mount the 12.10 Desktop Edition `.iso` file to 4GB USB. The computer i'm trying to install does not support USB booting. But by going to Hard Drives --> Extra Plugin in boot many(<kbd>F12</kbd>), it does allow USB booting. and it opens and shows the error `invalid or corrupt kernal image boot:`.

I guess if I give the directive to the booting file which it asks for, it will allow me to install. Or what should I do to install it? This same error has shown before when I tried to install it through CD.

The above method is what I tried last. I have tried many ways. By using USB Installer, the error is `UI Directive not found`, or something like that. It was caused by my USB being NTFS.

**Edit:**
I formatted my USB to FAT32. My C:/ is already FAT32.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working. I formatted usb in fat16 and used universal usb installer to mount iso and now its done. I've installed it. But i dont think i want Ubuntu now, because this seems pretty slow, 'cause this pc is pretty old. It have Pentium 4 @ 3 GHz, Ram - 1.2GB.

I searched web and found out Xubuntu. I've downloaded the iso. Now this is my new problems.

To format the drive and to mount the iso, i went to startup disk creator. It failed to format the drive. So i just deleted the files in it and clicked on make the drive. Xubuntu booted for install, but showed some error. I guess it's 'cause its because the format wasn't done. Help me.

Answer (score 0):

Before [burning the Image file to DVD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto) or [copying it to USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromImgFiles), i think you should test the checksum of the downloaded file.

[Here you can re-download the .ISO file if needed](http://releases.ubuntu.com/quantal/).